# How to use Selenium for testing webpages in different browsers on Android?

Tags: selenium

It doesn't seem to me like there is much Selenium support for browser testing on mobile devices. From what I can gather the Selendroid driver is intended for testing mobile apps, [not web apps](https://github.com/selendroid/selendroid/issues/199). Chrome seems to have it's own support through the [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started/getting-started---android), however this only covers 1 browser. I still need to test for at least firefox and if possible the native android internet browser (does this have a name?).

I want to stick to Selenium because we already have a large set of automated tests in Selenium being used to test on desktop browsers. It's also a requirement that we test on real devices, so emulators are out of the question.

Would it work if I installed the Selenium Standalone Server on an Android device and used something like [TerminalIDE](http://terminal-ide.com/) to do:

```
  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-{VERSION}.jar
```

And then connect with RemoteWebDriver?

Are there no selenium drivers for android intended for browser testing?

Edit: [Appium](http://appium.io/) is another alternative for android (and also iOS) however again it doesn't seem like it supports the Firefox browser.

Comment: Chrome is doable on android using Selendroid and chromedriver.
For firefox you will need the apk?Gotta switch to the webview and then start testing. Assuming it is the same as the Selendroid webview app itself.
Regarding the native android browser. I havent found a solution for that yet.

Comment: @MadisKangro As it turns out Appium can actually use the native android browser, and seems to have Selendroid built in as well. However I'm still not able to get either Selendroid or Appium to work with Firefox the same way they work with Chrome.